# How can I get Logger.BeginScope to work with Application Insights?

Tags: logging, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-application-insights

I've read somewhere that Application Insights should work with structured logs, and I'm trying to log data to Application Insights using ILogger's BeginScope:

```cs
using (_logger.BeginScope("Some really useful information"))
{
    // something something

    _logger.LogError("Oh no.");
}
```

However, when inspecting the trace in Application Insights, I'm not getting the log data from BeginScope, just "Oh no" in this case.
This is a .NET Core 2.0 application.
Is BeginScope not supported with the default implementation of Application Insights ILogger? Or am I missing something?

Comment: This does work for me nowadays, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore package version 2.19.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this problem by using Serilog with it's Application Insights sink. Worked perfectly.

Comment: How do you "begin" a scope with the Serilog sink?

Answer (score 0):

Application Insights does not yet directly support 'Scopes', but it's in feature backlog.
https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/issues/491